# Insert a new element in a specified position of a list

Tags: scala

There is no built-in function or a method of a List that would allow user to add a new element in a certain position of a List. I've wrote a function that does this but I'm not sure that its a good idea to do it this way, even though it works perfectly well:

```
def insert(list: List[Any], i: Int, value: Any) = {
  list.take(i) ++ List(value) ++ list.drop(i)
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> insert(List(1,2,3,5), 3, 4)
res62: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I would suggest using `.splitAt` rather than `.take` and `.drop` (to avoid going over the list twice).

Comment: This would probably be much more appropriate at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I am going to answer in the spirit of that site.

Comment: "There is no built-in function or a method of a List that would allow user to add a new element" But there is such a method -  it is called `patch`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## Type Safety

The most glaring thing I see is the lack of type safety / loss of type information. I would make the method generic in the list's element type:

```
def insert[T](list: List[T], i: Int, value: T) = {
  list.take(i) ++ List(value) ++ list.drop(i)
}
```

## Style

If the body only consists of a single expression, there is no need for curly braces:

```
def insert[T](list: List[T], i: Int, value: T) = 
  list.take(i) ++ List(value) ++ list.drop(i)
```

## Efficiency

[@Marth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650437/marth)'s comment about using [`List.splitAt`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@splitAt(n:Int):(List[A],List[A])) to avoid traversing the list twice is also a good one:

```
def insert[T](list: List[T], i: Int, value: T) = {
  val (front, back) = list.splitAt(i)
  front ++ List(value) ++ back
}
```

## Interface

It would probably be convenient to be able to insert more than one value at a time:

```
def insert[T](list: List[T], i: Int, values: T*) = {
  val (front, back) = list.splitAt(i)
  front ++ values ++ back
}
```

## Interface, take 2

You could make this an extension method of `List`:

```
implicit class ListWithInsert[T](val list: List[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def insert(i: Int, values: T*) = {
    val (front, back) = list.splitAt(i)
    front ++ values ++ back
  }
}

List(1, 2, 3, 6).insert(3, 4, 5)
// => List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

## Closing remarks

Note, however, that inserting into the middle of the list is just not a good fit for a cons list. You'd be much better off with a (mutable) linked list or a dynamic array instead.

Comment: Great answer. Minor nitpick : you could replace `front ++ List(values:_*) ++ back` with `front ++ values ++ back`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I was too focused on keeping close to the original.

Comment: Little off top: why `ListWithInsert` `extends AnyVal`?

Comment: @dmitry: Why not? After all, enrich-my-library was one of the primary motivators for introducing value classes in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't realize that such a service for code reviews exists. I will definitely use it in the nearest future with some more scala examples

Answer (score 32):

You can also use `xs.patch(i, ys, r)`, which replaces `r` elements of `xs` starting with `i` by the patch `ys`, by using `r=0` and by making `ys` a singleton:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 5).patch(3, List(4), 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

In [the Scala course by his eminence Martin Odersky himself, he implements it similarly to](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun2/lecture/62Xed/lecture-3-6-discrete-event-simulation-implementation-and-test)

```
def insert(list: List[Any], i: Int, value: Any): List[Any] = list match {
  case head :: tail if i > 0 => head :: insert(tail, i-1, value)
  case _ => value :: list
}
```

One traversal at most.