# Add element to specific index of list

Tags: scala, list

What is the best way of adding to a specific index of a list in scala?

This is what I have tried:

```
case class Level(price: Double) 

case class Order(levels: Seq[Level] = Seq())

def process(order: Order) {
    orderBook.levels.updated(0, Level(0.0))
}
```

I was hoping to insert into position zero the new `Level` but it just throws `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` . What is the best way of handling this? Is there a better data type other than `Seq` which should be used for keeping track of indexes in a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037384/scala-insert-a-new-element-in-a-specified-position-of-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better data type other than Seq which should be used for
>   keeping track of indexes in a list?

Yes, a `Vector[T]` is recommended when you want random access into the underlying collection:

```
scala> val vector = Vector(1,2,3)
vector: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> vector.updated(0, 5)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(5, 2, 3)
```

Note that a `Vector` will also through an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to insert data into an empty vector. A good way of appending and prepending data is using `:+` and `:+`, respectively:

```
scala> val vec = Vector[Int]()
vec: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector()

scala> vec :+ 1 :+ 2
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you use the newly updated Vector to overwrite the existing one stored in `Order`? How about if you want to insert (not update) into the Vector?

Comment: @maloney You can use a `var vector` field and keep updating it. Or, you can choose another mutable collection as needed. Insert is as I've shown using `:+` and `+:`.